# How to get google app script function/variable in html ref tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a url entries in google app script.
I used the tag `<??>` to write the code inside it. but it prints the name of function not the job of it.

```
<a id="a1" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1tC7hfPCbELEcYeck18P6EaMQORRiClAYVJlt-60jU0g/viewform?entry.1258467517=<?Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();?>&entry.861732986&entry.174249007=unsatisfied"><input id="in" type="button" value="Unsatisfied" ></a>
```

So how I get the the function print in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, the notation for executing a function is:

`<?= ?>`, you forget the equals.

And you didn't show, but there could also be an error in the function to serve the page, it's a common error not to use `createTemplateFromFile` and `evaluate`:

```
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
```